# optimize has weird behavior when I change the interval

Tags: r, loops, intervals, mathematical-optimization, maximize

I have a problem with `optimize()` in R.

When I only change the interval in `optimize()`, surprisingly, the optimal parameter value will vary a lot. I found posts with similar problems before, but there is no answer for them.

I got really different values from different intervals:

```
c(-1,1): -0.819 

c(-1,2): -0.729 
c(0.3,0.99):0.818 
c(0.2,0.99):0.803 
c(0.1,0.99):0.23 
c(0,0.99):0.243
```

I really need help on this problem, thank you guys if you could help or give me any information!!

**edit**: here is a picture of the objective function:

[image]

My code is as below:

```
dis<-data[,5]
vel<-data[,3]
condition<-data[,2]
nrow<-nrow(data)
number<-500
status<-0
counter<-rep(0,nrow)
firstvel<-rep(0,nrow)
secondvel<-rep(0,nrow)
j=1
n=1
l=0
secondpoint<-rep(0,nrow)
f<-function(a,b,p){ 
  for (i in 5:p){
    diss<-dis[1:(i-1)] 
    stddis<-sd(diss)    
    lowerdis<- a*stddis
    upperdis<- b*stddis
    if (status==0&&dis[i]>=upperdis){
      status<-1
      firstvel[j]<-vel[i]
      j=j+1    
    }
    else if (status==1&&condition[i]<=condition[i-1]&&dis[i]<lowerdis){
      status<-0
      secondvel[n]<-vel[i]
      n=n+1
    }
  }
  secondvel<- subset(secondvel, secondvel>0)
  firstvel<- subset(firstvel, firstvel>0)
  if (j==n&&j>1){
    for (k in 1:(j-1)){
      unit<-number/firstvel[k]
      number<-unit*secondvel[k]
    }
  }   else if(j>1) {
    for (k in 1:(j-2)){
      unit<-number/firstvel[k]
      number<-unit*secondvel[k]
    }
    unit<-number/firstvel[k+1]
    number<-unit*vel[p]
  }
  return(-number)
}
for (point in 300:nrow){
  diss<-dis[1:(point-1)]
  stddis<-sd(diss)
  upperdis<- stddis
  if (status==0&&dis[point]>=upperdis){
    status<-1
    firstvel[j]<-vel[point]
    j=j+1
    last<-optimize(f,c(0.2,0.99),b=1.0,p=point)
    secondpoint[n]<-last$minimum      ## This is the optimal value I need, which changes a lot 
    lowerdis<- secondpoint[n]*stddis
  }
  else if (status==1&&condition[point]<=condition[point-1]&&dis[point]<lowerdis){
    status=0
    secondvel[n]<-vel[point]
    n=n+1
  }
}
secondvel<-subset(secondvel,secondvel>0)
firstvel<-subset(firstvel,firstvel>0)
secondpoint<-as.numeric(secondpoint[1:(j-1)])
diff<-rep(0,(j-1))
if (j==n&&j>1){
  for (k in 1:(j-1)){
    unit<-number/firstvel[k]
    number<-unit*secondvel[k]
    diff[k]<-unit*(secondvel[k]-firstvel[k])
  }
}  else if(j>1) {
  for (k in 1:(j-2)){
    unit<-number/firstvel[k]
    number<-unit*secondvel[k]
    diff[k]<-unit*(secondvel[k]-firstvel[k])
  }
  unit<-number/firstvel[k+1]
  number<-unit*vel[nrow]
  diff[k+1]<-unit*(vel[nrow]-firstvel[k+1])
}
```

Comment: this isn't reproducible.  What is `diss`?  I would start by drawing a picture of your curve, e.g. `mvec <- seq(-4,4,length=201); qvec <- sapply(mvec,fun,n=2,p=50); plot(mvec,qvec,type="l")`

Comment: Ben's point is that all such optimization algorithms move to the nearest local minimum.  If your starting point is over there, you won't converge to over here.

Comment: Actually, not even necessarily the *nearest* local minimum -- all that is guaranteed is *a* local minimum ...

Comment: @BenBolker I made the image with your code, and since I can't upload picture here:(, I will try to describe it to you. The picture has a lot of flat parts, so I can understand that it varies around 0.2, cause that's the true optimal value of the minimal objective function. Then the function goes up after that. I don't know why it would be 0.803 for (0.2,0.99).

Comment: And there is actually a abrupt decrease in (0.8,0.81), but the objective function value is way larger than the others.

Comment: you could upload to e.g. imgur.com or give us a dropbox link ... or show us the data to make the example reproducible.  A verbal description isn't really going to be enough.

Comment: Thank you so much!!https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp3fto36e3bh1ab/Rplot.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This optimization problem is essentially going to be impossible for any optimizer (such as `optimize()`) that assumes the objective function is smooth and has a single minimum.  You didn't give a reproducible example, but here's an example of an objective function that's just about as ugly as yours:

```
set.seed(101)
r <- runif(11)
f <- function(x) r[pmin(11,pmax(1,floor(x)+1))]
```

There are many stochastic global optimizing algorithms -- you can search the [CRAN Optimization Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) for "global" to find more -- but they will all be much slower, and require a great deal more tuning of optimization control parameters, to get reliable results for any particular problem.  In this case, the `"SANN"` (simulated annealing) method from `optim()` works reasonably well with the default options -- it gets the right answer 20 out of 25 times.  You could adjust the control parameters (e.g. increase `maxit`: see `?optim`) and perhaps do better.

```
pvals <- replicate(25,optim(f,par=5,method="SANN")$par)

curve(f,from=-1,to=11)
points(pvals,f(pvals),col=2)
sum(pvals>1 & pvals<2) ## 20
```

[image]

Alternatively, for a 1D problem brute-force grid search is always an option ...

Comment: I tried optim() with combining m and n as a vector, but it doesn't work. So I will make it reproducible for you later, thank you a lot for your help, that's really nice!:)

Comment: Btw, do you have email or what that I can send you my reproducible code? Thank you!

Comment: You should try to figure out how to strip your example down enough that you can post a reproducible version of it here.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm new here, and I posted my reproducible code above. Sorry that I have so many questions...

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not reproducible because we don't have your data.  Can you please clarify in what way my answer does *not* provide a sufficient starting point for you to solve your problem?

Comment: Oh sorry it's my bad, the data is huge. I changed it as you suggested, last<-optim(par=0.1, f,method="SANN",control = list(maxit = 10000)). But it always returns error:objective function in optim evaluates to length 0 not 1.

Comment: that means there's something wrong with `f` (which is funny since it was working with `optimize`). If `f` has parameters `a` and `b` then you need to call `optim` with those arguments included: `optim(par=0.1, f,method="SANN",control = list(maxit = 10000), a=...,b=...)`

Comment: That's why I don't get it, I did initialize them in the function, which is the same as:last<-optim(par=-1, f,b=1,p=point,method="SANN",control = list(maxit = 10000)) Then I still have the error...

Comment: unfortunately these kinds of questions are very hard to debug remotely.  That's why it's worth the effort to try to strip down/simplify your question to something that can be reproduced.  Could your question still work with a small subset of your data? Have you tried the usual suite of debugging tricks (putting `cat()` statements in your code; using `debug()` or putting `browser()` calls in your code; using `options(error=recover)` ?)

Comment: I tried, but it only works when I had like 300 rows in my initial data matrix. When I shrink it to 200, they have similar values all the time, but...it's still not the optimal value. Do you think it's because my function is too messy?

Comment: is there any chance you can get some local help?

Comment: Thank you a lot yesterday! I changed the optimization method, and just got the minimum manually, and ironically, this is more accurate.