# R optim function not converging

Tags: r

I am trying to optimize 3 parameters for a function. When I pass different initial guesses into optim, I get different optimized values back, even though it returns convergence 0 (meaning true)! My cost function is determinate. UPDATE: sample cost function provided below - it is discontinuous with a if/else statement

```
ol_cost_func <- function(coeffs, fitting_data){
   fitted <- coeffs[1] + fitting_data$x1 * coeffs[2] + fitting_data$x2 * coeffs[3]
   value <- ifelse(fitted > fitting_data$y, fitting_data$z - fitted, 0)
   return(mean(value))
}

optim(c(-0.01, -1, -.6), ol_cost_func, fitting_data = data, control=list(fnscale=-1))

$par
[1] -0.02915648 -1.00824819 -0.55884414

$value
[1] 5.047735

$counts
function gradient 
     340       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

optim(c(-0.01, -1, -.4), ol_cost_func, fitting_data = data, control=list(fnscale=-1))

$par
[1] -0.07138303 -1.03042150 -0.30845815

$value
[1] 6.654118

$counts
function gradient 
     273       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: It may be determinate but most clearly it has multiple local minima. `optim` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do (and **can** do) -- converging to the closest solution to your starting point.

Comment: fair enough. is a different function the right one? e.g. nlm?

Comment: maybe `optim(.,method="SANN")` -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809480/optimize-has-weird-behavior-when-i-change-the-interval/23812220#23812220 -- but it would probably help to understand the nature of the objective function surface better.

Comment: You might try to do it in Optimx (a newer replacement for optim). There are a few different optimisation checks done that might shed some light on it.

Comment: the example linked above is even closer than I thought -- it's another example of a discontinuous objective function surface.

Comment: see also p. 27 of http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/chap7A.pdf

Comment: thanks - this is helpful. "SANN" is actually producing worse results than just the default method, but I'll try some of the other ones in the book...

Comment: the book generally otherwise covers local optimization.  You will need some form of stochastic global optimization, or tweak your objective function to make it smooth.